# How to extract substrings from string and store them as key value pair

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var txt = "af86abf7-89b5-40f6-9099-5228f72aea88\t3984088\t` Jack Bob \t1\
t35631407838\t\t19650098\têdce27f38-07b7-40f4-b64a-a6bc8814fcb7\t4101111\t`  JOHN MAROTI \t1\
t829234079446\t\t19600101\tê0b9a12ba-9b7c-484e-84bf-d75fcb18aa66\t2955999\t` BAYANABAI BUIPJ\t1
\t\t\t0\tê1795bec6-e28e-4749-a528-0d9a6082ca99\t2664383\t`JASON ASHOK MLOAP\t1\t\t\
t0\têada976ea-02f4-41f1-a1ec-397288dea7hh\t2569898\t`WILLY DHANRAJ AABJK\t2\t\t\t0";
```

I want to extract only names (ex: "Jack Bob" and "JOHN MAROTI") and specific numbers ("t984088" and "t4101111") from above string and save them as key-value pairs.

example:
KEY= 3984088, VALUE=Jack Bob from the below part of the string:

```
af86abf7-89b5-40f6-9099-5228f72aea88\t3984088\t` Jack Bob \t1\
t35631407838\t\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression: `` /([0-9]+).?`.?([a-zA-Z ]+)/g ``
This will match all name, key pairs.

I recommend using the website [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help create regular expressions like this.

[Live Code Example](https://codepen.io/niiyeboah/pen/MWKPpEy)

Answer (score 1):

there are at least 2 ways to do this: via a replace

```
var pairs = {};
txt.replace(/\t(\d+)\t`([^\t]+?)\t/g, (_, key, value) => {
  pairs[key] = value.trim();
});
console.log(pairs);
```

or via an utility/helper

```
function asKeyValuePairs(txt) {
  var re = /\t(\d+)\t`([^\t]+?)\t/g;
  var pairs = {};
  while (re.test(txt))
    pairs[RegExp.$1] = RegExp.$2.trim();
  return pairs;
}
```

where `asKeyValuePairs(txt)` will return the desired object.

Feel free to not `.trim()` values if that's undesired.